# tcp android client server c linux vm

Tags: android, c, linux, server, tcpclient

Hi and thanks for reading my question. I am implementing a simple android application to communicate with a server written in c on a linux virtual machine.
My problem is that the connection doesn't happen, the server remains listenin, Socket is created and binded but device is not found.

**java code**

```
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TCPClient {

    private String serverMessage;
    /**
     * Specify the Server Ip Address here. Whereas our Socket Server is started.
     */
    public String serverIp; // your computer IP address
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 7755;
    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener;
    private boolean mRun = false;

    private PrintWriter out = null;
    private BufferedReader in = null;

    /**
     * Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
     */
    public TCPClient(final OnMessageReceived listener, String ipAddressOfServerDevice) {
        mMessageListener = listener;
        serverIp = ipAddressOfServerDevice;
    }

    /**
     * Sends the message entered by client to the server
     *
     * @param message text entered by client
     */
    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
            System.out.println("message: " + message);
            out.println(message);
            out.flush();
        }
    }

    public void stopClient() {
        mRun = false;
    }

    public void run() {

        mRun = true;

        try {

            //here you must put your computer's IP address.
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIp);

            Log.e("TCP SI Client", "SI: Connecting...");

            //create a socket to make the connection with the server
            try (Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT)) {

                //send the message to the server
                out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

                Log.e("TCP SI Client", "SI: Sent.");

                Log.e("TCP SI Client", "SI: Done.");

                //receive the message which the server sends back
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
                while (mRun) {
                    serverMessage = in.readLine();

                    if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                        //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                        Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");
                    }
                    serverMessage = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TCP SI Error", "SI: Error", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
            // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP SI Error", "SI: Error", e);

        }

    }

    //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
    //class at on asynckTask doInBackground
    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        void messageReceived(String message);
    }
}
```

Serverip contains the address of the server that is on the virtual machine and I get it from the command ipconfig and is entered by the user through a simple editText and then go to another screen where you can send messages to the server.

**server side**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX 80
#define PORT 7755
#define SA struct sockaddr

void func(int sockfd)
{
    char buff[MAX];
    int n;
    for(;;)
    {
        bzero(buff,MAX);
        read(sockfd,buff,sizeof(buff));
        printf("From client: %s\t To client : ",buff);
        bzero(buff,MAX);
        n=0;
        while((buff[n++]=getchar())!='\n');
        write(sockfd,buff,sizeof(buff));
        if(strncmp("exit",buff,4)==0)
        {
            printf("Server Exit...\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int sockfd,connfd,len;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cli;
    sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sockfd==-1)
    {
        printf("socket creation failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n");
    bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port=htons(PORT);
    if((bind(sockfd,(SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)))!=0)
    {
        printf("socket bind failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    printf("Socket successfully binded..\n");
    if((listen(sockfd,5))!=0)
    {
        printf("Listen failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("Server listening..\n");
    len=sizeof(cli);
    connfd=accept(sockfd,(SA *)&cli,&len);
    if(connfd<0)
    {
        printf("server acccept failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("server acccept the client...\n");
    func(connfd);
    close(sockfd);
}
```

**logcat error**

```
2021-04-30 08:53:17.109 29809-30311/com.example.androdi_socket_example E/TCP SI Client: SI: Connecting...
2021-04-30 08:53:17.116 29809-30311/com.example.androdi_socket_example E/TCP SI Error: SI: Error
    java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 7755) from /:: (port 47378): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:143)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:570)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:450)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:250)
        at com.example.androdi_socket_example.socket.client.TCPClient.run(TCPClient.java:64)
        at com.example.androdi_socket_example.socket.client.MyActivity$connectTask.doInBackground(MyActivity.java:81)
        at com.example.androdi_socket_example.socket.client.MyActivity$connectTask.doInBackground(MyActivity.java:65)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
        at libcore.io.Linux.connect(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.connect(ForwardingOs.java:95)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:136)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.connect(ForwardingOs.java:95)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:157)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:135)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142) 
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390) 
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230) 
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212) 
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436) 
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621) 
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:570) 
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:450) 
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:250) 
        at com.example.androdi_socket_example.socket.client.TCPClient.run(TCPClient.java:64) 
        at com.example.androdi_socket_example.socket.client.MyActivity$connectTask.doInBackground(MyActivity.java:81) 
        at com.example.androdi_socket_example.socket.client.MyActivity$connectTask.doInBackground(MyActivity.java:65) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

**EDIT**
I solved this problem by enabling listening on a port of my virtual machine (Virtual Box) following this [guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/#:%7E:text=To%20forward%20ports%20in%20VirtualBox%2C%20first%20open%20a%20virtual%20machine%27s,click%20the%20Port%20Forwarding%20button.)

Comment: `failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 ` Well.. what are you doing?

Comment: That does not match `//here you must put your computer's IP address.
`

Comment: `I get it from the command ipconfig and is entered by the user through a simple editText` Did you type in 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Being my server written on a virtual machine I had to enable the porting solving my problem